# RxJS: Chained Observables Not Using the Same Root Observable Values

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I'm trying to learn RxJS and I was attempting to build what I thought would be a simple and straightforward example. Create an observable of random numbers generated on an interval, then use two other observables based on that observable to track the lowest and highest values that had been seen.

The rngStream seems to behave as expected, minStream and maxStream both appear to track correctly as well. The problem I'm having is that when this executes it seems like rngStream, minStream, and maxStream all have different random numbers on each interval. I'm trying to understand if that's expected or if I've just set something up incorrectly.

My goal would be an output something like:

```
[27, 27, 27]
[13, 13, 27]
[90, 13, 90]
[42, 13, 90]
...
```

```js
let rngStream = Rx.Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .map(() => Math.ceil(Math.random()*100))
  .take(5);

// Track the lowest number we've seen.
let minStream = rngStream
  .startWith(100)
  .scan((x, y) => Math.min(x, y))

// Track the highest number we've seen.
let maxStream = rngStream
  .startWith(0)
  .scan((x, y) => Math.max(x, y))

Rx.Observable.zip(rngStream, minStream, maxStream)
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.2/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LKMwkuK0ZE

This video actually clarified a lot of things for me. Specifically at the 32:00 mark he mentions `.share` which makes an observable multicast. By default every subscriber does get its own copy. So the fix looks like this:

```js
let rngStream = Rx.Observable
  .interval(1000)
  .map(() => Math.ceil(Math.random()*100))
  .take(5)
  .share();

// Track the lowest number we've seen.
let minStream = rngStream
  .startWith(100)
  .scan((x, y) => Math.min(x, y))

// Track the highest number we've seen.
let maxStream = rngStream
  .startWith(0)
  .scan((x, y) => Math.max(x, y))

Rx.Observable.zip(rngStream, minStream, maxStream)
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.2/Rx.min.js"></script>
```